# Read Django urls.py, models.py, views.py file content from Database tables

Tags: django, django-models

I want to create an application, which need to create dynamic application, dynamic models, dynamic urls, dynamic database from web-ui.

When i click on create new application button, it need to create a new database, new models, new app and add entry to the settings.py.

Please provide some suggestion.

Comment: You would just have to create `.py` files with the content you need, it is not that hard.  What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have created a Django project ,django application and installed a mysql database. I am able to create a simple web application and can able to do interactions with the database like GET and POST. But how to create it all Dynamically in the run time. So far i have done it in a static manual way